# Why isn't the UJT always on in a relaxation oscillator?

Tags: capacitor, oscillator

I can't understand why current doesn't always run through Vs to R3 to emitter to B1 to R1 and then to ground since it appears that the supply voltage will constantly apply a voltage to the emitter.

Whenever I read or watch something on this topic they always say that the supply voltage pulls the electrons from the positive side of the capacitor to charge it but wouldn't that same pull, pull the electrons from B1 through the emitter of the UJT?

[image: Relaxation Oscillator]

Comment: If R3 < "Some value of resistor", UJT would be always ON, and it is not thus a relaxation oscillator.

Comment: You copied that image from the Electronics Tutorials web page that explains how UJTs and UJT relaxation oscillators work. Which part of the description needs further explaining?

Comment: @Justme I copied it from another stack exchange post. Can you post the link to the web page you mentioned?

Comment: Source for the original image is here : https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/power/unijunction-transistor.html

Comment: https://www.technicalbookspdf.com/unijunction-transistor-ujt-with-operation-applications/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the described current flow causes conductivity modulation in the base.  Normally B1-B2 is a modestly high resistance; when current flows, the resistance drops.  E is connected midway along the B1-B2 resistor, thus it experiences negative resistance, as well as transistance to B2 (i.e., E-B1 current causes the effect, but it also occurs at B2).

Because it is a negative resistance effect, it can indeed be swamped by too-high or too-low current flow.  Such a circuit only works over a modest range of current values.